# Command not found assignement array script bash

Tags: c, arrays, bash

Bash in Linux give me `command not found` error in `Line 9` where I do `$array[$i]="Name_Of_File$i"`.
There are also the correct numbers printed besides the error. But i can't figure how it is possible. Maybe some spaces ? On the net i fuond these sintax of writing assignement with an array.

```
declare -a array;
start=0;
NumFile=$(ls -1 -d log/log_cassiere* | wc -l);
for (( i=$start; i<$NumFile; i++))
do
   $array[$i]="Name_Of_File$i";
done

echo ${array[0]};
```

Comment: Don't use `$` on the left side of assignments. Paste the entire script into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to see various suggestions and the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with:

```
$array[$i]="Name_Of_File$i"
```

is that it is actually *interpreting* `$array[$i]` because you have a `$` preceding it. That means it will attempt to replace the left side of the assignment with the value. Instead, you should have:

```
array[$i]="Name_Of_File$i"
```